# How to use a list in other function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list like this `cs_id["CS_A1","CS_b7",...]` in a function. At the end of the function the list ist filled with 80 values. How can I use this list (and values) in another function? Here I want to use the list `cs_id[]` from function unzip in function `changecs`. (By the way, the second function isn't ready yet.)

### Update

I still dont get it....dont know why.

Here is my full code...maybe someone can help.

**maker.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import getopt
import sys
import functions as func

ifile = ''
ofile = ''
instances = 0

def main(argv):
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hi:o:n:d", ["help", "ifile=", "ofile=", "NumberOfInstances="])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        func.usage()
        sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            func.usage()
            sys.exit()
        elif opt in '-d':
            global _debug
            _debug = 1
        elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
            global ifile
            ifile = arg
        elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
            global ofile
            ofile = arg
        elif opt in ("-n", "--NumberOfInstances"):
            global instances
            instances = int(arg)

    func.unzip(ifile, instances)
    func.changecs()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**functions.py**

```
import os
import zipfile
import sys
import string
import random

# printing usage of warmaker.py
def usage():
    print "How to use warmaker.py"
    print 'Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ' -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile> -n <NumberOfInstances>'

# creating random IDs for CS instance e.g. CS_AE, CS_3B etc.
def id_generator(size=2, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

# unzip the reference warfile and build n instances
def unzip(ifile, instances,):
    newinstance = ifile
    cs_id = []
    for i in xrange(instances):
        cs_id.append('CS_' + id_generator())
        i += 1
    print 'Searching for reference file ' + newinstance
    if os.path.isfile(newinstance):  # check if file exists
        print 'Found ' + newinstance
    else:
        print newinstance + ' not fonund. Try again.'
        sys.exit()
    print 'Building ' + str(instances) + ' instances... '
    for c in xrange(instances):
        extract = zipfile.ZipFile(newinstance)
        extract.extractall(cs_id[c])
        extract.close()
        print cs_id[c] + ' done'
        c += 1
    return cs_id

#def create_war_file():

def changecs(cs_id):
    n = 0
    for item in cs_id:
        cspath = cs_id[n] + '/KGSAdmin_CS/conf/contentserver/contentserver-conf.txt'
        if os.path.isfile(cspath):
            print 'contentserver-conf.txt found'
        else:
            print 'File not found. Try again.'
        sys.exit()
        n += 1
    #f = open(cspath)
    #row = f.read()
```

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways.

#### 1/ Return the list in unzip

```
def unzip(ifile, instances):
    # No need for this global
    # global cs_id 

    cs_id = []
    # Do stuff
    # [...]

    # Return the list
    return cs_id
```

In this case you can call unzip and get the complete list as return value:

```
def changecs(instances):

    # The following line is equivalent to
    # cs_id = unzip(ifile, instances) 
    # for c in cs_id:
    for c in unzip(ifile, instances):

        cspath = cs_id + '/abc/myfile.txt'
```

#### 2/ Pass it as a parameter and modify it in unzip.

```
def unzip(ifile, instances, cs_id):
    # Do stuff
    # [...]
```

In this case you can pass unzip the empty list and let it modify it in place:

```
def changecs(instances):

    cs_id = []

    unzip(ifile, instances, cs_id):

    for c in cs_id:

        cspath = cs_id + '/abc/myfile.txt'
```

I prefer the first approach. No need to provide unzip with an empty list. The second approach is more suited if you have to call unzip on an existing non-empty list.

### Edit:

Since your edit, `unzip` returns `cs_id` and `changecs` uses it as an input.

```
def unzip(ifile, instances,):
    [...]
    return cs_id

def changecs(cs_id):
    [....]
```

But you call them like this:

```
func.unzip(ifile, instances)
func.changecs()  # This should trigger an Exception since changecs expects a positional argument
```

You should call them like this:

```
variable = func.unzip(ifile, instances)
func.changecs(variable)
```

or just

```
func.changecs(func.unzip(ifile, instances))
```

Comment: You can accept the answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow/86979#86979

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to initialize the list outside of the function, then call it in both, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the function and return it to the other function. Not sure where you'd want to use it but as an example this is the same concept

```
def foo():
    l = [1,3,2,5,4,6,5]
    l.append(10)

    return l

def bar():
    l = foo()
    print (l)
```

return terminates the function and in your case you'd want to put it at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Make `unzip` return the value. Call `unzip` from the main block. Then pass the return value from `unzip` into `changecs`. Simple.

```
def unzip(...):
   ...
   return cs_id

def changecs(cs_id, ...):
   ... do stuff with cs_id ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
   ... main block ... # This can be replaced with any kind of driver code
```

Alternatively, you can call `unzip` directly from within `changecs` (if that flow is permissible).

Answer (score 0):

The code is all but there. At the bottom of `def unzip()` the array `cs_id` is being returned using the `return` command. The returned array can be stored in a variable from the function which runs `unzip()`. In this case, it's our main python function.

After you have the `cs_id` array in a variable in your main function, pass it to `changecs()` like: `func.changecs(cs_id)`

Edit last two lines of `def main(argv)` to:

```
cs_id = func.unzip(ifile, instances)
func.changecs(cs_id)
```

In the above code, `unzip(ifile, instances)` returns our array `cs_id`. We pass this into `changecs(cs_id)` as an parameter.